# Solve for $y'' - 4y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wanted to check my answer. So I have the characteristic equation: $$r^{2}-4=0\Rightarrow r^{2} = 4 \Rightarrow r = \pm 2.$$

So the general solution is: $$y = c_{1}e^{-2t}+c_{2}e^{2t}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes you have the correct exponents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing here is that your claim is that your functions *satisfy* the differential equation.    So,  for example, with $y=e^{2t}$,   we'd calculate $y'=2e^{2t}$,  then $y''=4e^{2t}$.  Plugging these into $y''-4y$,  we see we get $4e^{2t}-4e^{2t}=0$, so this function does indeed satisfy the differential equation.

You can check the $e^{-2t}$ solution similarly.   And adding a constant multiple will clearly not change anything :).

Knowing that that is a complete solution set means they are linearly independent, which they are.